# Struct pointer contains pointer to char (string) , how to allocate memory for it?

Tags: c

Excuse my english , my program crashes as it is , but when i change the struct member `*name` (string) to `name[50]` and remove the command `(students+i)->name = (char*)malloc(50 * sizeof(char));`  the program works fine , so i guess the problem is that i do something wrong when dynamically allocating memory for each name.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student
{
    char *name;
    int grade;
};

int main()
{
    int student_number = 0,i;
    struct student *students = NULL;

    printf("Give the number of students: ");
    scanf("%d",&student_number);

    students = (struct student*)malloc(student_number * sizeof(struct student));

    for(i=0;i<student_number;i++)
    {
        (students+i)->name = (char*)malloc(50 * sizeof(char));

        system("CLS");

        printf("Give the name of student no. %d: ",i+1);
        scanf(" %s",&(students+i)->name);
        printf("Give the grade of student no. %d: ",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&(students+i)->grade);
    }

    system("CLS");

    for(i=0;i<student_number;i++)
    {
        printf("%d. %s %d\n",i+1,(students+i)->name,(students+i)->grade);
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think it's the `&(students+i)->name` in `scanf`. That gives the *address of the pointer* as the parameter, not the *address of the memory to store the name*.

Comment: `scanf(" %s",&(students+i)->name);` --> `scanf(" %s",(students+i)->name);` or `scanf(" %s", students[i].name);`

Comment: "Avoid answering questions in comments."

Comment: It worked , thank you both!

Comment: The program works fine now , but if i change this command scanf("%d",&(students+i)->grade); to scanf("%d",(students+i)->grade); it crashes , just for learning purposes could anyone explain why?

Comment: @user202729 I wasn't sure that was the case and I hadn't checked, which is why I put it in the comments. I like to reserve answers for when I'm more confident.

Comment: ... why downvote? Is this too easy? I don't think this can be searched at all, although the question as-is is not too useful to be searched. The asker does show their code, and when it crashes, what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the correct ways to call C `scanf` function are:

```
scanf("%d", int*)
scanf("%s", char*)
```

This is incorrect:

```
scanf("%s", char**)
```

Consider the working code:

```
int grade;
char name [50];
scanf("%d", &grade);
scanf("%s", name);
```

Here `grade` is an `int` variable, so `&grade` is the pointer to a `int` variable, having type `int*`. So this is correct.

`name` is an array of `char`, when passed to `scanf` it decays to a `char` pointer (type `char*`) point to the first element of the array. So this is also correct.

```
char name [50];
scanf("%s", &name);
```

`&name` is a pointer to an array of `50` `char`s, having type `char(*)[50]`, so technically this is incorrect, but it happens to work because the pointer have the same value as `&name[0]` or `(char*) name`.

```
struct a { int x; int y; };
a b;
scanf("%d", &b);
```

This code is also wrong, but happens to work because `&b` have the same value (most of the time) as `&b.x`, so the code will have identical functionality to

```
scanf("%d", &b.x);
```

although the pointer types are different. Don't rely on the behavior, anyway.

```
int grade;
scanf("%d", grade);
```

This crashes because `grade` is not a pointer to a `int`.

Now consider dynamically allocated array (of course, remember to call `free(name)` when you've done using it).

```
char* name;
name = (char*) malloc(50 * sizeof(char));
```

Consider using `calloc` instead. But anyway, in this case, `name` is a `char` pointer that point to the first byte of the allocated memory. So

```
scanf("%s", name)
```

is correct, because `name` is a `char*` pointing to the allocated memory, as I said above.

```
scanf("%s", &name)
```

`&name` is the pointer to the char pointer `name`, having type `char**`. Incorrect.

---

In conclusion, use `&` wisely. Don't stick to the pattern `scanf("format", &variables)`.

---

Unrelated note: Don't use `(students+i)->name`, use `students[i].name` instead. It's much clearer.

Comment: Don't forget to free the memory you have allocated for char* / struct * , or it will lead to memleak

Comment: @cslrnr Thanks, added.

Comment: Super answer!Thanks , much apreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, remove the '&' in the scanf(" %s" &(students+i)->name)
This is because it is already a pointer, and the '&' makes it a pointer to a pointer when it asks for just a pointer. After adding this change it works fine for me.